# Is it possible, to highlight bars in Dimple.js bar chart, based on y-axis value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I'm just wondering is it possible at all in Dimple.js, to highlight bars based on the y axis value ? I have a bar chart with 3 series - X as a CategoryAxis (RefNum), Y as a MeasureAxis (in K's) and Y2 as a PctAxis (in %). On top of the Bars we draw a line, calculated using javascript (e.g. Pareto chart). So the idea is to change the color of those bars, which are over 80% (of Y2), or maybe grey those out, well some how highlight them. Was digging the Dimple.js API documentation, but nothing there ... Also, I've tried to create a simple IF ELSE statement on

> myChart.defaultColors= [
>         new dimple.color("blue"), ];

but without any luck ... Is it possible at all, as I can't find any documentation or tutorials... Ideally, we would like to have something like this:
[image]
Not very familiar with the d3, maybe some solutions available through it ? We using dimple.js 2.1.6 and d3.v3
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Here is full code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.6.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 450px"></div>
<div id="chartContainer2" style="height: 450px"></div>  

 <script>


 var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", "100%", "100%");
 var data =[
 { "Project":"one","Cost":3586900, "Ref":"AB-46" },
 { "Project":"two","Cost":1509270, "Ref":"AB-47" },
 { "Project":"three","Cost":1409250, "Ref":"AB-48" },
 { "Project":"four","Cost":1305270, "Ref":"AB-49" },
 { "Project":"five","Cost":1109270, "Ref":"AB-50" },
 { "Project":"six","Cost":1009270, "Ref":"AB-51" },
 { "Project":"seven","Cost":909270, "Ref":"AB-52" },
 { "Project":"eight","Cost":809270, "Ref":"AB-53" } ];

/*** get the total Cost ****/
var totalAmount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
data[i].Cost = +data[i].Cost;
totalAmount += data[i].Cost;

if(i > 0){
   data[i]['CumulativeAmount'] = data[i].Cost + data[i-1].CumulativeAmount;
}else{
  data[i]['CumulativeAmount'] = data[i].Cost;
}
}


// calculate cumulative % from the cumulative amounts & total, round %
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  data[i]['CumulativePercentage'] = (data[i]['CumulativeAmount'] / totalAmount );
  data[i]['CumulativePercentage'] = parseFloat(data[i]['CumulativePercentage'].toFixed(2));
  }

var myChart= new dimple.chart(svg, data);
x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Ref");
//x.addOrderRule("x", "Ref");

y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Cost");
y2 = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "CumulativePercentage");
y2.tickFormat = "%";
y2.overrideMin = 0;
y2.overrideMax = 1;

var y3 = myChart.addPctAxis("y", "CumulativePercentage");   
y3.hidden = true;

s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar, [x, y]);
s2 = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line, [x, y2]);
s2.lineWeight = 3;                  

/***** get the value of the 80% of 'CumulativePercentage'   */
s3 = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.area, [x, y2]);

/**** make it invisible, to use custom d3 line later on *****/
s3.lineWeight = 0;

/****** get the 80% of cumulative percentages ****/
s3.data = [{
    "CumulativePercentage": 0.8
}]; 

myChart.draw(1500);

/***** draw a vertical line at 80% of calculated cumulative percentage line on top of the bars *****/

        svg.append("line")
           .attr("x1", x._scale(s3.data["CumulativePercentage"]))
           .attr("x2", x._scale(s3.data["CumulativePercentage"]))
           .attr("y1", myChart._yPixels())
           .attr("y2", myChart._yPixels() + myChart._heightPixels())
           .style("stroke", "red")
           .style("stroke-dasharray", "15")                                                                                                                             
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is what happen when I add an order rule to the x axis, e.g. `x.addOrderRule("Ref", true);`
[image]

But I need that chart looks like this:
[image]

Any thoughts on how to perform this ?! Thanks in advance for your help and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add this in with straight `d3`.  Something like:

```
myChart.svg.selectAll(".dimple-bar").filter(function(d) {
  return d.y > 60
}).style("fill", "red");
```

Where `myChart` is your dimple chart and `d.y > 60` is your criteria (**y** is the data variable holding your y2 values).

---

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="chartContainer"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);

    var data = [{
      x: 'one',
      y: 10
    }, {
      x: 'two',
      y: 80
    }, {
      x: 'three',
      y: 70
    }, {
      x: 'four',
      y: 30
    }, {
      x: 'five',
      y: 20
    }, {
      x: 'six',
      y: 6
    }];

    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
    var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "x");
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
    myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    myChart.draw();


    myChart.svg.selectAll(".dimple-bar").filter(function(d) {
      return d.y > 60
    }).style("fill", "red");
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**EDITS**

I suspect the problem might be that you don't actually have any data bound to that 2nd axis.  So, if you want the bar value with respect to the axis you can do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="chartContainer"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);

    var data = [{
      x: 'one',
      y: 10,
      anotherY: 1
    }, {
      x: 'two',
      y: 80,
      anotherY: 2
    }, {
      x: 'three',
      y: 70,
      anotherY: 3
    }, {
      x: 'four',
      y: 30,
      anotherY: 4
    }, {
      x: 'five',
      y: 20,
      anotherY: 5
    }, {
      x: 'six',
      y: 6,
      anotherY: 6
    }];

    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 510, 305)
    var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "x");
    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y");
    var anotherY = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "anotherY");
    myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
    myChart.draw();

    console.log(myChart);

    myChart.svg.selectAll(".dimple-bar").filter(function(d) {
      var val_of_bar_on_other_scale = anotherY._scale.invert(y._scale(d.y));
      return val_of_bar_on_other_scale > 2
    }).style("fill", "red");
    
  </script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks good, however, I've updated the question (I really should do this first, but ..), I have 2 Y axises, one for the numbers in 000' and one for the percentages. Your solution works absolutelly fine with the numbers and won't work with the second Y axis (%). So if I try this: `myChart.svg.selectAll(".dimple-bar").filter(function(d) {
      return d.y2 > 60
    }).style("fill", "red");`  it doesn't do anything. Confused now, why it works well with tyhe numbers, and won't work with the % axis ... Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: @user3891065, not near a computer right now but inspect the d variable via a console.log or break point in that filter function.  Your second y axis variable will be a property of it.

Comment: did inspect that in console.log, and it shows that this variable (d.y) holds a first Y(k's) axis value, but not the second Y (%) ... And the second Y axis is Udefinied, when I run that function .. So, confused even more now .. lol

Comment: Thanks a lot, works as a charm !!! Actually, the value was binded to the y2 (I was calculating it, the Cumulative Percentage), but for some reasons your first suggestion didn't get it. But when I tried your updated function, it does the trick ! Thanks a lot Mark, will mark your answer as a right one. Cheers !

Comment: Sorry Mark, maybe you can help me with this as well, what if I'd like to change the color of those bars, which are over 80% but not based on Y2 axis values, but on calculated Cumulative percentages line (s3 series in my case). I do calculate it and draw a line (e.g. Pareto chart). You can see on the screenshot, that first 3 bars are under these 80%, so I want to highlight them. Sorry for missunderstanding, your answers were solving exactly what I did ask, but looks like I confused myself with this chart ... do you have any thoughts on how I can do that or is it possible at all ? Thanks

Comment: the number of bars will change every time, but these 80% of calculated value on the line over the bars will remain the same. And number of highlighted bars will be different every time. So basically, I'm looking for the solution on how programatically do this ..?! Because I can't find the answer, how I can do that based on the s3 series (line). I hope my explanation make any sence to you ..

Comment: @user3891065, can you recreate your chart as a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), I think I understand what you are asking but it's difficult to answer without seeing running code.

Comment: @user3891065, that makes so much more sense now.  Seeing your data, I would actually do this another way.  Iterate your data and find the bar to change instead of iterating the bars.  See this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/La8NIelPPwWlZJ2IVpES?p=preview).

Comment: Thank You very much for Your time and for Your effort Sir, works exactly like as it should ! I do really appreciate your help !!!!!! Thank You !!!!!

Comment: I have a last question, if you don't mind Mark: is it possible to change the order of series to make chart readable from left to the right, using my example data? When I add an order rule, like: x.addOrderRule("Ref", true);  what is happen, the bars are changing (e.g. decrease order, left to right), but the line remain on the same place(screenshot 2). And I would like that it looks like on screenshot 3 (e.g. proper Pareto chart). Is it possible in Dimple ?! Or it is again possible through the d3 ... ?! Any thoughts? Cheers

Comment: Finally sorted, adding new empty series s3 surprisingly solved a problem. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but at least it draw a chart in correct order. Thanks !